# How to return all results using REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Tags: regex, oracle

I need four results to be returned, and only three are showed. How could I do this?

Query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(lines, '[0-9]{1,3}', 1, 1,'m')
from 
(
      SELECT '111 - first line' lines FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '222 - second line'      FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT '333 - third  line
              444 - fourth line' FROM dual
)
```

It's returning this:

```
111
222
333
```

I want this:

```
111
222
333
444
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think so... NO! Cause in last select you have 333 & 444 in same column. you need to normalize you data.

Comment: Yes it is, using CONNECT BY. I try to make an example. I think it is available from 9i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first lets make some data:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (some_data VARCHAR2(200))
/
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('111 - first line')
/
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('222 - second line')
/
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('333 - third  line
444 - fourth line')
/
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('555 - fifth  line
                         666 - some ugly line')
/
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('123 - meh meh
                         321 - one more
                         678 - and more
                         986 - and more :)')
/
```

Then let's make a query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(some_data,'[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1, level)) 
      FROM some_table
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(some_data, '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

You can easy implement your query to this. I was a little bit lazy to think, so i put a DISTINCT to remove repeating ROWS. In proper code you should not use it.

Your data will look like this:

```
333 - third  line
678 - and more
986 - and more :)
321 - one more
555 - fifth  line
444 - fourth line
666 - some ugly line
222 - second line
123 - meh meh
111 - first line
```